# Code ownership after SVN Merge

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

me and my office friend work on a common project maintained by SVN. We have a very simple Repository i-e no complex server client scheme, the Repository resides in network and we access Repository with file operations e-g "file:///F:/group/development/Path/to/SVN/Repository".

At the beginning I created the basic structure of the project, My friend started later by creating her own branch (after creation of this new branch no one else "including both of us" committed to trunk) and she kept on working in her own personal "branch". After around 20 commits she came to me and asked how to merge her "branch" back to the "trunk". So I merged her "branch" back to the "trunk" from my workplace. Now when I take a look at the files by using "blame" function I see that all her code is listed against my name. But when I take a look at the commit log I see it is perfectly listed against her name.

Please can someone put some light on it, is there anything we did wrong.

Comment: There is nothing wrong.  That's simply how SVN merge works.  Because you are doing the merge, and the corresponding change is under your name, that's it.  Normally such kind of feature branch should be merged by the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more complete answer :)

(As quoted from my comment)  There is nothing wrong. That's simply how SVN merge works. Because you are doing the merge, and the corresponding change is under your name, that's it. Normally such kind of feature branch should be merged by the author

Here is the way to fix the "incorrect" author.  First find out the revision that you commit the merge.  Then you can set the revision property to update the author:

```
svn propset --revprop -r MERGE_REV svn:author YOUR_FRIENDS_USER_NAME
```

Comment: Adding a bit of note to it, once `Blame` is used there is an option to `include merge info` and by that it will list the users edited the same file in all its merged branches as well for the corresponding task branch you are wokring.